# Will event be triggered before I set up the listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

```
var a = new Image();
...
// Is it possible that `load` happens here, so I won't be able to catch it?
...
a.onload = function () {};
```

Well, I guess the `load` event won't be triggered earlier.

How does the browser magically ensures that, by running code round by round? So events only triggered after it finished current round?

The code below won't output anything, is it because by using `setTimeout` we make `foo` runs on ***another round***?

```
var a = require('child_process').spawn('ls', ['-l']);

setTimeout(function foo() {
  a.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is this server-side code or client-side code?  If it's server-side (I'm guessing because of `ls -l`,  the browser magically ensures nothing.

Comment: @JNovack It's about how javascript deal with events, as `node` uses `v8`, I guess both client and server share the same idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the browser magically ensures that, by running code round by round? So events only triggered after it finished current round?

Yes. Or at least it should, I don't think it is 100% ensured in all browsers and all edge cases (for example cached files). So you should start the loading (by assigning the `src` property) always after setting up the listeners:

```
var a = new Image();
// Is it possible that `load` happens here? No.
a.onload = function () {};
a.src = "";
// Is it possible that `load` happens here? Yes
```

> The code below won't output anything, is it because by using setTimeout we make foo runs on another round?

Exactly. Of course, it could somehow (unlikely) happen that your server is slow and `ls -l` takes more than a second to before output, then you'd catch it.

Answer (score 1):

The code will not produce anything, because as you suspected, it completes BEFORE you set up the listener.

```
Time   Event
00.000 Spawn Child process 12345 `ls` with arguments `-l`  (a)
00.001 Set Timeout for function foo() in 1 second.
00.011 child process 12345 terminated with data. (a)
01.001 Running foo()
01.002 Attach 'data' event to `a`
```

Basically, you missed the bus (literally if you think of it as a serial bus)

You SHOULD not use the setTimeout and chain it if you want it to catch it.

```
var a = require('child_process').spawn('ls', ['-l']).stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```